# What is the smallest plausible size for a kinetic bombardment projectile based on the pure tungsten rod concept?

Tags: meteors

Related: [What would an impact from kinetic bombardment be like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290969/what-would-an-impact-from-kinetic-bombardment-be-like)

I am trying to calculate the size of the smallest possible tungsten projectile that can hit the ground without burning up in the atmosphere. Assuming this would imply kinetic energy at the time of impact $\geq 10^6$ joules, although not sure how to approach the calculation for the atmospheric burnout part to get the size *before* entry.

Comment: Do you intend to **drop** this tungsten projectile from a orbit?

Comment: Yes, but I am assuming anything going into it dropping from orbit is negligible. So just a pure tungsten rod at terminal velocity.

Comment: A tungsten rod (TR) released from a satellite will do a great big NOTHING! As the satellite  orbits the earth, so does the TR. Releasing it means it stays in orbit, with its satellite. You cannot 'drop' anything from an orbit because angular momentum and kinetic energy are conserved.

Comment: Trust me, the 'Rods from the Gods' (or whatever they call it) is an **urban myth**.

Comment: @Gert that's what I mean by "anything going into it dropping from orbit". Imagine some magic retrograde burn is applied until it only has a direct downwards trajectory

Comment: I don't think such a point can be achieved. If you reduce the tangential (orbital) velocity (with some retrograde rocket motor) the TR will enter lower and lower orbits, until it hits the earth. A direct downwards trajectory will not be possible, I think.

Comment: @Gert it would converge towards it. Also taking into account sideways friction after entry, assuming it will have the downwards trajectory at entry already would make it easier for a toy model

Comment: It would be simpler to assume a stationary spaceship firing such a projectile at the centre of the earth.

Comment: That's a simpler way to word it I guess. I was rather trying to avoid the velocity at entry becoming a significant factor

Comment: Choose a small $v(o)$?

Comment: Sure, terminal velocity at sea level maybe

Comment: Calculating what you're looking for is EXTREMELY demanding, mathwise. I doubt if you'll have any takers here.

Comment: A tungsten object could be easily de-orbited from a satellite by kicking it free with a compressed spring, as is done in MIRV-type nuclear warheads.

Comment: @nielsnielsen What does 'de-orbiting' really mean here?

Comment: It means having a thrust applied to it which subtracts from its orbital velocity, causing it to settle into a lower (decaying) orbit in which aerodynamic braking will make it fall the rest of the way through the atmosphere.